# Define vm function correctly in Controller As

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in javascript and AngularJS.

So... May be is a stupid question, but I have two way to define functions in javascript.

**In the following to controllers please look at "grupoCancha" and "grupoVisible"** (I pasted the hole script because there are another variable to defined depends the function)

**Controller:**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('example.cancha')
    .controller('CanchaController', CanchaController);

CanchaController.$inject = ['$state', 'canchaService'];

function CanchaController($state, canchaService) {
    var vm = angular.extend(this, {
        canchasComplejo: [],
        grupoCancha: grupoCancha,
        grupoVisible: grupoVisible
        });



    (function activate() {
        cargarCanchasComplejo();

    })();

    //funcion que llama al servicio para obtener las canchas del complejo
    function cargarCanchasComplejo() {
        canchaService.obtenerCanchasComplejo()
            .then(function(canchasComplejo) {
                vm.canchasComplejo = canchasComplejo;
            });
    }


    function grupoCancha(canchaComplejo){
        if (vm.grupoVisible(canchaComplejo)) {
            vm.grupoMostrado = null;
        } 
        else {
          vm.grupoMostrado = canchaComplejo;
        }
    }

    function grupoVisible(canchaComplejo){
       return vm.grupoMostrado === canchaComplejo;
    }


}
})();
```

The other way is kinda weird (may be is because I come from Java). But the definition of the function is complicated:

**Controller 2:**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('example.cancha')
    .controller('CanchaController', CanchaController);

CanchaController.$inject = ['$state', 'canchaService'];

function CanchaController($state, canchaService) {
    var vm = angular.extend(this, {
        canchasComplejo: []
        });



    (function activate() {
        cargarCanchasComplejo();

    })();

    //funcion que llama al servicio para obtener las canchas del complejo
    function cargarCanchasComplejo() {
        canchaService.obtenerCanchasComplejo()
            .then(function(canchasComplejo) {
                vm.canchasComplejo = canchasComplejo;
            });
    }

    vm.grupoCancha = function(canchaComplejo) {
        if (vm.grupoVisible(canchaComplejo)) {
            vm.grupoMostrado = null;
        } 
        else {
          vm.grupoMostrado = canchaComplejo;
        }
    };

    vm.grupoVisible = function(canchaComplejo) {
        return vm.grupoMostrado === canchaComplejo;
    };


}
})();
```

**Could you explain me which way is the best to define functions and why?**
Thanks!!

Comment: what is you question?? **Can you expain me why is the best wey to define the function and why?** PLEASE CHECK YOUR ENGLISH!!

Comment: @Aravind Sorry. Solved

Comment: But can u tell me whats your question?

Comment: @Aravind, Simple: there are 2 way to write the same function, see the function "grupoCancha": In the first controller is written different than the second controller. What function is more recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to write Java Script. However stick on to recommended usage as specified in the documentation.
Remember that performace is the concern in large scale applications. So [**Minfication**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) is the way to achieve it.

I have modified your **Controller 1** which will look like

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('example.cancha')
    .controller('CanchaController', 
                ['$state', 
                'canchaService',
                CanchaController]);
/*Order of dependencies in both should be one and the same as it will be usefull for minification of your code*/

function CanchaController($state, canchaService) {
    var vm = this ;

        canchasComplejo: [],

        vm.grupoCancha=function (canchaComplejo){
                if (vm.grupoVisible(canchaComplejo)) {
                    vm.grupoMostrado = null;
                } 
                else {
                    vm.grupoMostrado = canchaComplejo;
                }
        }
    //funcion que llama al servicio para obtener las canchas del complejo
    ////Sugesting to use exception handling below as it makes a service call.
        vm.cargarCanchasComplejo=function() {
                canchaService.obtenerCanchasComplejo()
                        .then(function(canchasComplejo) {
                        vm.canchasComplejo = canchasComplejo;
                        });
        }

        vm.grupoVisible=function(canchaComplejo){
                return vm.grupoMostrado === canchaComplejo;
        }
    }
}());
```

When you **minify** this code it looks as below

```
!function(){"use strict";function a(a,b){var c=this;c.grupoCancha=function(a){c.grupoVisible(a)?c.grupoMostrado=null:c.grupoMostrado=a},c.cargarCanchasComplejo=function(){b.obtenerCanchasComplejo().then(function(a){c.canchasComplejo=a})},c.grupoVisible=function(a){return c.grupoMostrado===a}}angular.module("example.cancha").controller("CanchaController",["$state","canchaService",a])}();
```

So I suggest you **[Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)** by John Papa.

Hope this might help you

Stick on to one pattern, ensure that the team works in the same pattern.

**Hope it is helpful :)**.

Comment: is it helpful??

Answer (score 0):

the only difference I see is using vm with two last functions in your second code sample. When you use

```
function grupoVisible(canchaComplejo){
   return vm.grupoMostrado === canchaComplejo;
}
```

this function is private to the current JS code of your controller (since your controller is immediately executed - `(function(){})()`) and is not accessible from the HTML. When you write it as

```
vm.grupoVisible = function(canchaComplejo) {
    return vm.grupoMostrado === canchaComplejo;
};
```

it may be later accessed in HTML via ng-controller="CanchaController as cc" and then cc.grupoVisible, for example:

```
<div ng-controller="CanchaController as cc">
  <button ng-if="cc.grupoVisible()">SOME BUTTON</button>
</div>
```